# How to write a TSQL query with nested CASE in IF statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to generate a `TSQL` query like this:

```
IF @GenderOfEmployee IS NOT NULL
    CASE @GenderOfEmployee = 1
        THEN INSERT INTO @NotAllowedGenderOfJobPost (TagID) values (139)
        ELSE INSERT INTO @NotAllowedGenderOfJobPost (TagID) values (138)
    END;
```

I mean I want have a `CASE` statement in `IF` statement.
Is it possible?

Consider I don't want other similar ways to provide that query.

Thanks for your advanced help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change like this

```
IF @GenderOfEmployee IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO @NotAllowedGenderOfJobPost (TagID) SELECT CASE WHEN @GenderOfEmployee = 1
        THEN 139
        ELSE 138
    END
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a `select` to insert the result of a `case` expression:

```
declare @NotAllowedGenderOfJobPost as Table ( TagId Int );
declare @GenderOfEmployee as Int = NULL;

-- Try NULL.
if @GenderOfEmployee is not NULL
  insert into @NotAllowedGenderOfJobPost (TagId ) values
    ( case when @GenderOfEmployee = 1 then 139 else 138 end );
select * from @NotAllowedGenderOfJobPost;

-- Try 0.
set @GenderOfEmployee = 0;
if @GenderOfEmployee is not NULL
  insert into @NotAllowedGenderOfJobPost (TagId ) values
    ( case when @GenderOfEmployee = 1 then 139 else 138 end );
select * from @NotAllowedGenderOfJobPost;

-- Try 1.
set @GenderOfEmployee = 1;
if @GenderOfEmployee is not NULL
  insert into @NotAllowedGenderOfJobPost (TagId ) values
    ( case when @GenderOfEmployee = 1 then 139 else 138 end );
select * from @NotAllowedGenderOfJobPost;
```